# Saving learned weights of Neural Network?

Tags: java, opencv, neural-network

I have trained a Neural Network.

```
int iter = nnet.train(M, label,new Mat(), new Mat() ,param, CvANN_MLP.NO_OUTPUT_SCALE);
```

It works reasonably well. However, I would like to save the learned weights so that the Neural Network does not have to be trained every time it is required. Is it possible to save the learned weights and restore them so that I can just call 'predict()' ? I read the Open CV Java Documentation. It said it was possible but there was no mention on how to go about this. I would be grateful for any help! Thanks!

Comment: Can't you serialize the whole network?

Comment: Do you mean something like "SerializeObject.save("filename.net",nnet);" to save. And restore using "FeedforwardNetwork result=(FeedforwardNetwork)SerializeObject.load("filename.net") " ???

Comment: I just came across that in a book. I haven't tried it out. Is that what you meant? Will it work with Open CV??

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/ml/CvANN_MLP.html <-- it has load and save methods for xml/yml

Comment: Sorry! I couldn't find it!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the load and save functions which stores the model as a YAML or XML under the CvStatModel in  http://docs.opencv.org/java/.

Thanks everyone!